# Undocumented Excel Formula Syntax? =Rx:Ry

Tags: excel

I noticed this weird formula syntax in on of my inter-company Excel template.  One of the cells contains a formula like

```
=5:10
```

Excel seems to recognize this as a formula but it errors out.  What is going on here? Seems like maybe it's trying to sum up everything in rows 5 through 10 maybe?

Comment: If it errors then it is not a viable formula.  Entered normally it returns `#Value`.  Entered as an array it returns the value from `A5`.  So though it is recognized as an array formula it does nothing more than the regular formula `=A5`

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

The formula create a range of rows 5 to 10